# FBA Sharepoint 2013 using (actual) AD Account

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I want to create a custom login page that will receive AD credential input. Currently, I'm using `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`, but I noticed that the account is different than the actual AD Account. One is `Contoso\SPAdmin`, while the other is `i:0#.f|ADProvider:SPAdmin`.

Of course, I can make them both Site Admin, albeit will look weird having two "SPAdmin" in selection.

I'm wondering if I can:
a) Link both account.
b) Login with Windows Authentication from C# (using FBA only for display, not the usual popup)

Whichever approach is fine, as I'm not asking for two questions here. Or maybe you can give me any other approach, it's fine.
The point is to login using `Contoso\SPAdmin` from a custom login page.

Thanks before.